# Using Jenkins and PHP Code Sniffer in ANT Build Script

Tags: php, ant, jenkins, checkstyle, phpcodesniffer

I am using the PHP Code Sniffer plugins in Jenkins.
It generates a checkstyle.xml file but the jenkins server cannot parse the file

I get the following in the Build Console Output.

```
phpdox:
...
[exec]     Parsing checkstyle logfile failed: loading file 'logs/checkstyle.xml' failed.
[exec] [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AtomFrontEnd-Master/workspace/build/logs/checkstyle.xml] [Line: 345 - Column: 1] Fatal Error 5: Extra content at the end of the document
...

build:

Total time: 3 minutes 32 seconds
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/checkstyle.xml
[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing 1 files in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AtomFrontEnd-Master/workspace
[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing of file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AtomFrontEnd-Master/workspace/build/logs/checkstyle.xml failed due to an exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 345; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1745)
at hudson.plugins.checkstyle.parser.CheckStyleParser.parse(CheckStyleParser.java:67)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractAnnotationParser.parse(AbstractAnnotationParser.java:53)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFile(FilesParser.java:300)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFiles(FilesParser.java:258)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parserCollectionOfFiles(FilesParser.java:209)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:178)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:31)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:920)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:893)
at hudson.plugins.checkstyle.CheckStylePublisher.perform(CheckStylePublisher.java:143)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwarePublisher.perform(HealthAwarePublisher.java:144)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwareRecorder.perform(HealthAwareRecorder.java:333)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$2.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:32)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)


...
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsPublisher aborted due to exception
java.io.IOException: Expecting tag checkstyle
at hudson.plugins.violations.parse.AbstractParser.expectNextTag(AbstractParser.java:268)
at hudson.plugins.violations.types.checkstyle.CheckstyleParser.execute(CheckstyleParser.java:39)
at hudson.plugins.violations.parse.AbstractTypeParser.parse(AbstractTypeParser.java:57)
at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsCollector.doType(ViolationsCollector.java:187)
at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsCollector.invoke(ViolationsCollector.java:114)
at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsCollector.invoke(ViolationsCollector.java:25)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:920)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:893)
at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsPublisher.perform(ViolationsPublisher.java:74)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
```

This Server is running CentOS 6.5
PHP Version: 5.4.29
Apache Ant version 1.9.4

The checkstyle.xml file starts with  tag

```
<file ... >
    ...
</file>
```

When i run the same Ant build script from Ubuntu with the same Ant version , my checkstyle.xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <checkstyle version="2.0.0a2">
      <file ... >
         ...
      </file>
   </checkstyle>
```

Comment: The error message says `Expecting tag checkstyle`, and you already noticed that the `checkstyle` element is missing from the XML. So to me, it seems you just have to add the missing element around your XML.

Comment: Same issue in Windows 2k8 Enterprise :( Where excatly should this file be located? Is it "dummy" file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and when I turned on output in Ant I found that phpcs ran out of memory. After I increased the memory_limit in php.ini it generated a correct XML file.